# Keras: how to evaluate model accuracy (evaluate_generator vs. predict_generator)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am getting a different model accuracy from keras `evaluate_generator()` and `predict_generator()` for a binary classification problem:

```
def evaluate_model(model, generator, nBatches):
    score = model.evaluate_generator(generator=generator,               # Generator yielding tuples
                                     steps=generator.samples//nBatches, # number of steps (batches of samples) to yield from generator before stopping
                                     max_queue_size=10,                 # maximum size for the generator queue
                                     workers=1,                         # maximum number of processes to spin up when using process based threading
                                     use_multiprocessing=False,         # whether to use process-based threading
                                     verbose=0)
    print("loss: %.3f - acc: %.3f" % (score[0], score[1]))
```

With `evaluate_generator()`, I am getting `acc` values of up to **0.7**.

```
def evaluate_predcitions(model, generator):
    predictions = model.predict_generator(generator=generator,
                                    steps=generator.samples/nBatches,
                                    max_queue_size=10,
                                    workers=1,
                                    use_multiprocessing=False,
                                    verbose=0)

    # Evaluate predictions
    predictedClass = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
    trueClass = generator.classes
    classLabels = list(generator.class_indices.keys())

    # Create confusion matrix
    confusionMatrix = (confusion_matrix(
        y_true=trueClass,                                       # ground truth (correct) target values
        y_pred=predictedClass))                                 # estimated targets as returned by a classifier
    print(confusionMatrix)
```

With `predict_generator()`, I am getting `acc` values of **0.5**. 
I am calculating `acc` as `(TP+TN)/(TP+TN+FP+FN)`

---

- Am I right, that `acc` from `evaluate_generator()` is based on `TP+TN/(TP+TN+FP+FN)`?
- How can `acc` be different when I use the same data and generator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this issue (evaluate_generate & predict_generator accuracies). You simply need to do three things in your code:

(1) set

```
shuffle = False
```

in the `test_datagen.flow_from_directory` or `test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe`,

(2) set

```
workers = 0
```

in the `model.predict_generator` and (3) change

```
trueClass = generator.classes[generator.index_array]
```

These changes will make your program be executed on the main thread, rest the index and match with the image id. Then both accuracies should be the same.