# Dimensions problem with keras TimeseriesGenerator function + how to convert generator to single object with all data

Tags: python, keras, time-series, lstm

I want to train LSTM model using TimeSeriesGenerator. Here is the sample data:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras


X_train = pd.DataFrame(X[:50, :3]).to_dict()
data_dict = {0: {0: 17.03263553814233,
  1: 16.91773130053791,
  2: 16.880430969011925,
  3: 16.941212281508385,
  4: 17.06728136015525,
  5: 16.951460252480615,
  6: 16.88878546128022,
  7: 16.83633974954705,
  8: 16.839547021666732,
  9: 16.893047070188103,
  10: 16.908247408273184,
  11: 16.932061227796794,
  12: 16.70144454118497,
  13: 16.66517923074079,
  14: 16.59713738578013,
  15: 16.67469995149962,
  16: 16.64827817893891,
  17: 16.689412341406623,
  18: 16.745563889588468,
  19: 16.84815901998644,
  20: 16.82860048430865,
  21: 16.80598224635871,
  22: 16.772347951779608,
  23: 16.787230667980424,
  24: 16.655011192853294,
  25: 16.73827787518816,
  26: 16.72633573886843,
  27: 16.8401507524151,
  28: 16.702673077521396,
  29: 16.762289900352002,
  30: 16.586687597474594,
  31: 16.660249461764664,
  32: 16.707573930305628,
  33: 16.752390582119617,
  34: 16.708825403777027,
  35: 16.722208462947748,
  36: 16.72985951041818,
  37: 16.73602224988734,
  38: 16.65139978234363,
  39: 16.67022197897856,
  40: 16.86610115511084,
  41: 16.8482315125475,
  42: 16.833133725267032,
  43: 16.797556855127254,
  44: 16.78316620312438,
  45: 16.780553429685014,
  46: 16.806822449260707,
  47: 16.8451916415556,
  48: 16.94550168688282,
  49: 16.84370375684513},
 1: {0: 43000.0,
  1: 111800.0,
  2: 96400.0,
  3: 58700.0,
  4: 23900.0,
  5: 9100.0,
  6: 67900.0,
  7: 80200.0,
  8: 87400.0,
  9: 42100.0,
  10: 26100.0,
  11: 42900.0,
  12: 250400.0,
  13: 97500.0,
  14: 257800.0,
  15: 48900.0,
  16: 137300.0,
  17: 68700.0,
  18: 50200.0,
  19: 81200.0,
  20: 45200.0,
  21: 37800.0,
  22: 24300.0,
  23: 12700.0,
  24: 58400.0,
  25: 46500.0,
  26: 10400.0,
  27: 10000.0,
  28: 44300.0,
  29: 46300.0,
  30: 225000.0,
  31: 23900.0,
  32: 1000800.0,
  33: 71400.0,
  34: 29500.0,
  35: 149600.0,
  36: 117600.0,
  37: 89800.0,
  38: 50000.0,
  39: 63100.0,
  40: 28300.0,
  41: 8500.0,
  42: 34400.0,
  43: 22300.0,
  44: 60700.0,
  45: 8800.0,
  46: 43400.0,
  47: 75500.0,
  48: 136800.0,
  49: 24600.0},
 2: {0: 23.543331924769625,
  1: 23.3956762891149,
  2: 23.417613400194405,
  3: 23.859848685580317,
  4: 23.60976568548289,
  5: 23.538354361435772,
  6: 23.547637010902115,
  7: 23.552996092560093,
  8: 23.78698229934543,
  9: 23.664908494474194,
  10: 23.747881962380657,
  11: 23.683826412575037,
  12: 23.686379446852914,
  13: 23.687620700357115,
  14: 23.918675354407362,
  15: 23.904309666941682,
  16: 24.148060575406685,
  17: 24.13765511195884,
  18: 23.996674352326753,
  19: 23.998178700008626,
  20: 24.126958920350923,
  21: 24.04678460856936,
  22: 24.155977056578347,
  23: 24.14693905013938,
  24: 23.831879893861824,
  25: 23.84887261006559,
  26: 24.12559692458759,
  27: 24.11140163004467,
  28: 23.955514506550816,
  29: 24.04190979398875,
  30: 24.058656527592404,
  31: 24.12582514532358,
  32: 24.22946534475154,
  33: 24.20869509568419,
  34: 24.09349543840721,
  35: 24.187021249006563,
  36: 24.21144457575573,
  37: 24.13637519528531,
  38: 24.22781423971693,
  39: 24.2215057285322,
  40: 24.118051328759705,
  41: 24.112170255986804,
  42: 24.113874923758225,
  43: 24.114421718733333,
  44: 24.054540271482693,
  45: 24.06846432723949,
  46: 24.089484450162367,
  47: 24.018806212384856,
  48: 24.113251988260423,
  49: 23.89928510418779}}
X_train = pd.DataFrame(data_dict).values
y_train = X_train[:, 0]
```

And here is my the code:

```
# genrator
train_test_index_split = 0.8
train_generator = keras.preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator(
    data=X_train,  # sample.drop(columns=['close_orig']).values
    targets=y_train,
    length=5,
    sampling_rate=1,
    stride=1,
    start_index=0,
    end_index=int(0.8*X_train.shape[0]),
    shuffle=False,
    reverse=False,
    batch_size=10
)

# modeling
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.LSTM(20, return_sequences=True, input_shape=[None, X_train.shape[1]]),
    keras.layers.LSTM(20, return_sequences=True),
    keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(1))
])
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam')
history = model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=1, epochs=20, verbose=1)
pd.DataFrame(history.history).plot()
```

I get an error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: Incompatible shapes: [10,5,1] vs. [10,1]
     [[{{node loss_7/time_distributed_7_loss/SquaredDifference}}]]
     [[loss_7/mul/_641]]
  (1) Invalid argument: Incompatible shapes: [10,5,1] vs. [10,1]
     [[{{node loss_7/time_distributed_7_loss/SquaredDifference}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

I don't understand what's wrong with my dimensions.

**Bonus question.** Since there are some problems with function `evaluate_generator` and `predict_generator` ([Keras: how to evaluate model accuracy (evaluate_generator vs. predict_generator)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55868975/keras-how-to-evaluate-model-accuracy-evaluate-generator-vs-predict-generator)), and I have enough RAM, how can I convert generator to X ynd y with all data. Then I will be able to use usual predict and evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

When the `length` parameter is greater than 1 `TimeseriesGenerator` adds lagged features to each sample by appending `(length - 1)` previous rows. In your case `length = 5`, so you must take it into consideration when you build your model. You need to specify the correct input shape that is `length x X_train.shape[0]`, ie.:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.LSTM(20, return_sequences=True, input_shape=[None, 5, X_train.shape[1]]),
    keras.layers.LSTM(20, return_sequences=True),
    keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(1))
])
```