# Predict_generator giving same output value for all images (CNN- regression)

Tags: python, keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am doing image regression using a CNN. I am currently testing my model on 4K images but plan to expand to 12K images. My code works perfectly fine with Keras test_train_split.
I am trying to use ImageDataGenerator to allow me to load images in memory easily.

```
train_generator = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe= df,
                                          directory='ImageChips_Group1',
                                          x_col='EB_ID',
                                          y_col='TOT_P',
                                          subset = 'training',
                                          target_size = (img_height, img_width),
                                          seed=42,
                                          batch_size= Batch_size,
                                          shuffle= False,
                                          pickle_safe = True, 
                                          workers=1,
                                          class_mode='raw')


validation_generator = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe= df,
                                          directory='ImageChips_Group1',
                                          x_col='EB_ID',
                                          y_col='TOT_P',
                                          subset ='validation',
                                          target_size = (img_height, img_width),
                                          seed=42,
                                          batch_size= Batch_size,
                                          shuffle= False,
                                          pickle_safe = True, 
                                          workers=1,
                                          class_mode='raw')
```

My best score using fit_generator is loss: 39.3873 - val_loss: 20.0538 (MAE) since I am using Callbacks to store the best model I expect my evaluate and predict functions to have similar results.

```
ValScore = saved_model.evaluate_generator(validation_generator, 
                                          steps = validation_generator.n,
                                          verbose =1,
                                         )
print("Test set Accuracy = ", ValScore )

TrainScore = saved_model.evaluate_generator(train_generator, 
                                            steps = train_generator.n,
                                           verbose =1,
                                            )
print("Train set Accuracy = ", TrainScore)
```

However using evaluate I get 28.9 % and 50.8% on val and test set respectively.
Moreover I get worse results using predict_generator

```
 validation_generator.reset()  
 y_predict =saved_model.predict_generator(validation_generator,
                                            steps = validation_generator.n//validation_generator.batch_size +1,
                                            verbose=1)
```

I have found that my predictions are just repeating the same number. I also calculated MAE using the validation_generator.labels to get 39.51%. I don't understand why this is different from evaluate_generator (As my model has trained well I don't think there is anything wrong the data or the training, there is something wrong in the way its being evaluated )
Similar issues have been posted [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11754) and [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6499), which mainly point to setting shuffle=False and resetting the generator (which I did but didn't solve the issue).

Comment: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55868975/keras-how-to-evaluate-model-accuracy-evaluate-generator-vs-predict-generator)

Comment: I think the solution pointed towards just making sure Shuffle =false and workers =0 so that we make sure that the validation generator is exactly the same. Ive already ensured that and my prediction results are still grossly different

Answer (score 0):

It could also be that the problem is very hard to learn. I've had this and actually after 6 hours of identical outputs in each batch (which happens because the 'average' answer is the easiest to minimize loss), the network finally started learning:

[image]

Some things I plan on doing to make the learning happen earlier:

1. changes in learning rate
2. using features from earlier in the network